# Broadcast dynamic registration, "onReceive" not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

This is my simple test code where I try to dynamically register a receiver, but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyBroadacast broadacast;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("xyz");
        this.registerReceiver(broadacast, intentFilter);

        Intent intent = new Intent("xyz");
        intent.putExtra("some_text", "text");
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);

        broadacast = new MyBroadacast() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);
                String g = intent.getStringExtra("some_text");
                Log.d("ololo", "onReceive " + g);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It should show log messages but it doesn't.

Comment: You could see in debug mode that broadcast will be null at time of registration because it's initialised after using it instead it should be initialised first and then used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just change code order**

1. Initialize broadcast
2. Initialize intentFilter
3. Send broadcast

Initialize broadcast at first

```
broadacast = new MyBroadacast() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
            String g = intent.getStringExtra("some_text");
            Log.d("ololo", "onReceive " + g);
        }
    };
```

Then Initialize intentFilter

```
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("xyz");
        this.registerReceiver(broadacast, intentFilter);
```

Then send broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent("xyz");
    intent.putExtra("some_text", "text");
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: @Akylbek i missed some thing, i updated my answer please check it, you must initialize broadcast at first then initialize  intentFilter then sendBroadcast

Comment: It's seems that it's no difference to change code order. If this code work fine in your Android Studio, maybe it's problem of my studio.

Comment: @Akylbek See sure there are difference, how you use null object?!,  how to use object not Initialized ?!

Comment: It's works. It was my mistake. When I posted this problem I've changed code. Thank you!